# Remove only commas in quotations from a CSV in PowerShell

Tags: regex, excel, csv, powershell

My end goal is to convert/export data in some CSV files into an Excel workbook with multiple sheets using PowerShell. I have it about 90% working but I cannot seem to remove some commas in the contents of the CSV files.

I've tried some regular expressions but they didn't work.

My luck so far is that it either removes nothing or it removes every single comma in the CSV and then breaks the export to Excel by putting everything into a single column or it removes everything in the cell that has the comma in it.

Here's an example of some of the content of the CSV that I am trying to work with.

```
Software Name     Vendor

Software A        Vendor A
Software B        Vendor B
Software C        Vendor, C
Software D        Vendor D
Software E        Vendor, E
```

Here is a snippet of code from a script that I am putting together.

```
$Excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = $GetCSV.Count
$AddWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$NewWorkSheet=1

foreach ($CSV in $GetCSV) {
    (Get-Content $CSV | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $CSV
    $Row=1
    $Column=1
    $WorkSheet = $AddWorkBook.WorkSheets.Item($NewWorkSheet)
    $Name = $CSV.Name -replace ('.CSV','')
    $WorkSheet.Name = $Name
    $GetFile = (Get-Content $CSV)

    foreach($Line in $GetFile) {
        $LineContens=$Line -split ‘,(?!\s*\w+”)’
        foreach($Cell in $LineContens) {
            $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column) = $Cell
            $Column++
        }
        $Column=1
        $Row++
    }
    $NewWorkSheet++
}
$AddWorkBook.SaveAs($WorkBookName)
```

Comment: This isn't quite clear. For the CSV parsing, is there a reason you are not using Import-Csv? (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx). Where in the script are you trying to remove commas, or is it because you are trying to parse the CSV manually? If you use Import-CSV, and loop through that object, does that solve your issue?

Comment: Please learn to *indent your code*. It will make it infinitely more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

```
,(?!(?<=",)")
```

**Replace With:**  nothing

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find all commas which are not separating quote delimited value strings
- assumes all values are contained inside quotes

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/uY6iG1/2

**Sample text**

```
"Software Name","Vendor"
"Software A","Vendor A"
"Software B","Vendor B"
"Software C","Vendor, C"
"Software D,","Vendor D"
"Soft,ware E","Vendor, E"
```

**After Replacement**

```
"Software Name","Vendor"
"Software A","Vendor A"
"Software B","Vendor B"
"Software C","Vendor C"
"Software D","Vendor D"
"Software E","Vendor E"
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ",                       '",'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where do you get the regex graph images from?

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, perfect. Much appreciated.

Comment: you can use negative lookbehind..its well supported in powershell

Comment: @Robin The chart was created on https://www.debuggex.com/. @rock321987 yes you can use a negative lookbehind too, but `(?<!"),(?!")` runs two separate checks which functions as an 'or' statement. This would be different than the 'and' statement included in this answer.